# Telegram documents provider Uri to file path

Tags: java, android, telegram

I'm working on an application that reads a custom file format with IntentFilter. When main activity receive an uri form android authority (downloads, external sdcard, media documents) everything is fine, but I've noticed that when I try to open my file from a Telegram chat I get this custom provider :

`content://org.telegram.messenger.provider/media/..fileName..`

Unfortunately there is not documentation online about this, and I'm worried about how read the file from Telegram custom Uri authority.

**EDIT**

One possible workaround is to replace `content://org.telegram.messenger.provider/media/` with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` output. But I really don't think that this is the best solution.

Comment: Why cant you open that content scheme? Why would it cause a ploblem? Which code do you apply on it?

Comment: This is the problem, I don't know in which way I can open the uri. For android uri I use `getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, order)`, but for telegram provider what are the parameters? What should I project?

Comment: Your code does not open an uri. Does not open an InputStream for the uri.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your comment you must use `getContentResolver().query(URII, projection, selection, selectionArgs, order)` and URII is the uri you get from shared file. for columns(projection) use size and `display_name` and more if you want(read android Mediastore columns). Other argumants can be null.
And for getting thumbnail you can use this:

```
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                            context.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(path),
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options)
```

This can be true for every other share file app.